# Amending values in an array

Tags: powershell, array

I want to pull the available disk space from multiple servers and flag the values with low disk space (<20GB for example purposes). I am having trouble with flagging the low values.

To pull the Disk space, I run

```
$Array = gwmi win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName ComputerName | Select DeviceId, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}
```

Which returns data as expected;

```
DeviceId Size FreeSpace
-------- ---- ---------
A:          0         0
C:       79.9      14.3
D:        701     72.76
Z:          0         0
```

I can then query $Array.Freespace for the following;

```
0
14.3
72.76
0
```

As I want to flag any values less than 20 in this list, I have tried running the below code;

```
ForEach ($Value IN $Array.FreeSpace)
{IF ($Value -lt 20) {$Value = "WARNING"}
```

However, there are no changes to my array after running this. I believe the issue lies within `$Value = "Warning"` - Is this the correct way to change each individual value in a ForEach Loop?

As an end result I want the results to show the below when I query `$Array`:

```
DeviceId Size FreeSpace
-------- ---- ---------
A:          0     WARNING
C:       79.9     WARNING
D:        701     72.76
Z:          0     WARNING
```

Any help greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: The reason this is not working is because you are altering the retrieved value from the array, rather than the array itself. I bet the following IF would work `{IF ($Value -lt 20) {@_.FreeSpace = "WARNING"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can set array subitems in the way you are trying to. Try this approach instead.

```
> $Array = gwmi win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName ComputerName | Select DeviceId, @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}},@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}

> $array.freespace
144.56
146.88
0
2198.05

> foreach ($Drive in $Array) {IF ($Drive.Freespace -lt 20) {$Drive.Freespace = "WARNING"}}

> $array.freespace
144.56
146.88
WARNING
2198.05

> $array

DeviceId    Size FreeSpace
--------    ---- ---------
C:        220.26    144.56
D:        244.14    146.88
E:             0   WARNING
P:       3071.87   2198.05
```

Work through each item referencing the Freespace value.

Comment: Works a treat. Thank you. As you suggested, I think the issue lies within the Array subset query I tried to use... Foreach ($Value in $Array.Freespace) - as opposed to pulling the whole array and using the FreeSpace member for updates.